# Is there "Create Block" command in pyautocad?

Tags: python, autocad

I added 2 lines in autocad with pyautocad using acad.model.AddLine() command. Now i want to create block of this 2 lines(same as "Block" command in autocad). Is there any command in pyautocad to do this?

Answer (score 0):

As python is using ActiveX to drive AutoCAD, you should look at [this section](https://help.autodesk.com/view/OARX/2019/ENU/?guid=GUID-6FBF3CBD-AA1C-441D-B548-D3F0B3C851C6) of the ActiveX documentation.
Basically you have to add a new [Block](https://help.autodesk.com/view/OARX/2019/ENU/?guid=GUID-E6F7B03B-F5CC-4A18-9C48-BBF1D32A31FD) instance to the block collection of the drawing ([Blocks](https://help.autodesk.com/view/OARX/2019/ENU/?guid=GUID-E77CC5AD-74B8-472C-8270-32FD162D5653)), add the lines to this block definition and then insert a reference ([BlockReference](https://help.autodesk.com/view/OARX/2019/ENU/?guid=GUID-88EEBCA3-8AF5-4776-9D54-520B05AB9129)) into the model space with [InsertBlock](https://help.autodesk.com/view/OARX/2019/ENU/?guid=GUID-17F86FDD-B7FC-4F43-9F16-B4958F73A66D) method.

Comment: actually i'm working with pyautocad for a couple days, so it'll be great if you could show me with codes